# Print pdf document without opening print dialog box

Tags: javascript, php

Server side: PHP

How to print PDF documents without open the PDF file,

I have the set of PDF documents in one folder, i want to take print of that PDF file without opening the PDF file and Print dialog box,

Right now my design looks like this.

```
Print below document
```

> PDF Document 1
>
> PDF Document 2
>
> PDF Document 3
>
> PDF Document 4

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible - at least not on the front-end. Keep in mind that on the front-end, the end user is in control. The ability to print w/o user's permission/interaction would be a security flaw. A lot of programmers would take advantage of that just to screw with the end users ;)